# how to get the depthmap of the dataset Make3d?

Tags: depth, estimation

1) Train400Depth.tgz
    Laser Range data with Ray Position
    Data Format: Position3DGrid (55x305x4)
        Position3DGrid(:,:,1) is Vertical axis in meters (Y)
        Position3DGrid(:,:,2) is Horizontal axis in meters (X)
        Position3DGrid(:,:,3) is Projective Depths in meters (Z)
        Position3DGrid(:,:,4) is Depths in meters (d)

2) Train400Img.tar.gz
    Images all in resolution 2272x1704

http://ai.stanford.edu/~asaxena/learningdepth/data.html

Comment: Did you find out how it works?